# Unable to getElementById for loop-created cell in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I can't color my td element by javascript code. Console says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at index.html:96
```

I already tested it on basic panel:

```
<div id = "panel"></div>

let panel = document.getElementById('panel');
this.panel.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${color[0]},${color[1]},${color[2]},${color[3]})`;
```

**And it worked fine... Panel has changed color as i want.**

Here is the code that won't work:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (var k = 1; k <= 8; k++) {
    document.write("<td id = ",i,k,">" + "#" + "</td>");
    }
document.write("</tr>");
}   


let cell = document.getElementById('41');


this.cell.style.color = `rgba(${color[0]},${color[1]},${color[2]},${color[3]})`;
```

**In browser developer tools the cell already have id 41..**

Some code is missing, but the necessary is here. (Element getting colored by colorpicker.)
Is there a problem with generated id by for loop? How can I fix it?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: what is `this.cell` ?shouldn't it be `cell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have defined a variable called `cell` but are trying to access a *property* called `cell` on whatever `this` is.

Get rid of the `this.`

(If you were in the global scope **and** you had used `var` instead of `let`, then you would be creating a `window.cell` as a side effect so `this.cell` would work there … but you are using `let` so that isn't the case).

---

Your second problem is that the output of `document.write` will be buffered so that it can be inserted into the DOM after the `</script>` for the current script element. This won't happen until the script has finished executing.

You are using `getElementById` **too soon**. The HTML is sitting in the buffer, it hasn't been converted to DOM yet.

---

This is just one more reason to avoid using `document.write`. Use DOM methods such as `createElement` and `appendChild` instead.

As a bonus, this will give you a reference to the element so you don't need to go hunting through the DOM for it with `getElementById`.